# Using genetic algorithm for a matrix solution?

Tags: python, genetic-algorithm

I am looking for a GA library which can deal with my encoding and I would like to know if I can use my fitness function in a useful way.

My problems solution is looking like a matrix:

```
 [[0,2,3,0],
 [1,2,0,0],
 [0,2,0,0]]
```

All vectors will have length 8 (here they have 4 to make it smaller), the number of vectors is fixed for each problem, for complex problems, this is of course larger than 3.

Usually the GA deal with encoded problems like

```
[1,
 0,
 1,]
```

So instead of integers I have lists. My gene is not a vector but a matrix. I know I can consider a matrix as vector if I flatten it, but since I am not used to GA I thought maybe there are ways I dont have to.

My fitness function can assign each vector a score, so I can take out the good part of the genes - or is this not used in GA?

Is there a library in python which I can use with my encoding?